# Method called when optionmenu closes

Tags: android, optionmenu

I´m sure it´s on stackoverflow, I´ve been searching but I can´t find it. Which method is called when nothing in the optionsmenu is selected, but when it closes?

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.splashmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
```

And I´m missing one...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called **[onOptionsMenuClosed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsMenuClosed%28android.view.Menu%29)** .

```
@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);
    //do your business
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't this method get called?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it´s

```
  @Override
public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
  showingMenu = false;
  super.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu);
}
```